# my jquery is not access the php file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m relatively new to this php and I’m attempting to access/execute a php file from my javascript file and have it appear in my html. I was told $getjson is the best way to do that but I do not see my php script past backed into my html:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script src="Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>
     <a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>
    <div id="showdata"></div>
</body> 

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( document ).on("click","#getdata-button", function() {
    //test Confirmed
    alert('hello8');
       $.getJSON('Test.php', function(data) {
            //noresponse
            alert('hello5');
            $('#showdata').html("item1="+data.item1+" item2="+data.item2+" item3="+data.item3+"");
        });
    });
});
```

Test.php:

```
    < ?php
$items = array( 
  'item1' => 'I love jquery4u',
  'item2' => 'You love jQuery4u',
  'item3' => 'We love jQuery4u'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($items);

?>
```

My expected result is to item1/item2/item3 in the html.

Comment: What does it say in the Console anyways?

Comment: Check my answer, try it out and tell me if it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `(space)` character before `php`:

```
< ?php
```

Change it to: `<?php`.

Either, remove this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Or replace it with:

```
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
```

I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: I made those changes but nothing different occurred, I'm expecting to pass item 1 through 3 back to webpage.

Comment: Are both the PHP and the viewable files in the same folder?

Comment: both files are viewable in the same folder. Can you elaborate on what you mean by reviewing it in the console. I'm executing it directly from the webpage.

Comment: @bawg2005 Press F12 and see in the Dev Tools, there's an option called Console. See if there are any errors in it.

Comment: excellent. It says the 'access is denied'                                                                                     if ( s.username ) {
      xhr.open( s.type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password );
     } else {
      xhr.open( s.type, s.url, s.async );
     }

Comment: Man... This goes into a different problem... Enjoy solving it.